# Area of a Self-Intersecting Polygon

Tags: code-golf, geometry, restricted-time

Consider a potentially self-intersecting polygon, defined by a list of vertices in 2D space. E.g.

```
{{0, 0}, {5, 0}, {5, 4}, {1, 4}, {1, 2}, {3, 2}, {3, 3}, {2, 3}, {2, 1}, {4, 1}, {4, 5}, {0, 5}}
```

There are several ways to define the area of such a polygon, but the most interesting one is the even-odd rule. Taking any point in the plane, draw a line from the point out to infinity (in any direction). If that line crosses the polygon an odd number of times, the point is part of the polygon's area, if it crosses the polygon an even number of times, the point is not part of the polygon. For the above example polygon, here are both its outline as well as its even-odd area:

[image: Outline][image: Area]

<sup>The polygon will not in general be orthogonal. I've only chosen such a simple example to make it easier to count the area.</sup>

The area of this example is `17` (not `24` or `33` as other definitions or area might yield).

Note that under this definition the area of the polygon is independent of its winding order.

### The Challenge

Given a list of vertices with integer coordinates defining a polygon, determine its area under the even-odd rule.

You may write a function or program, taking input via STDIN or closest alternative, command-line argument or function argument and either return the result or print it to STDOUT or closest alternative.

You may take input in any convenient list or string format, as long as it's not preprocessed.

The result should either be floating point number, accurate to 6 significant (decimal) digits, or a rational result whose floating point representation is accurate to 6 significant digits. (If you produce rational results they are likely going to be exact, but I can't require this, as I don't have exact results for reference.)

You must be able to solve each of the test cases below within 10 seconds on a reasonable desktop machine. (There is some leeway in this rule, so use your best judgement. If it takes 20 seconds on my laptop I'll give you the benefit of the doubt, if it takes a minute, I won't.) I think this limit should be very generous but it is supposed to rule out approaches where you just discretise the polygon on a sufficiently fine grid and count, or use probabilistic approaches like Monte Carlo. Be a good sportsman and don't try to optimise of these approaches such that you can meet the time limit anyway. ;)

You must not use any existing functions related directly to polygons.

This is code golf, so the shortest submission (in bytes) wins.

#### Assumptions

- All coordinates are integers in the range `0 ≤ x ≤ 100`, `0 ≤ y ≤ 100`.
- There will be at least `3` and at most `50` vertices.
- There won't be any repeated vertices. Neither will any vertices lie on another edge. (There *may* be collinear points in the list, though.)

### Test Cases

```
{{0, 0}, {5, 0}, {5, 4}, {1, 4}, {1, 2}, {3, 2}, {3, 3}, {2, 3}, {2, 1}, {4, 1}, {4, 5}, {0, 5}}
17.0000

{{22, 87}, {6, 3}, {98, 77}, {20, 56}, {96, 52}, {79, 34}, {46, 78}, {52, 73}, {81, 85}, {90, 43}}
2788.39

{{90, 43}, {81, 85}, {52, 73}, {46, 78}, {79, 34}, {96, 52}, {20, 56}, {98, 77}, {6, 3}, {22, 87}}
2788.39

{{70, 33}, {53, 89}, {76, 35}, {14, 56}, {14, 47}, {59, 49}, {12, 32}, {22, 66}, {85, 2}, {2, 81},
 {61, 39}, {1, 49}, {91, 62}, {67, 7}, {19, 55}, {47, 44}, {8, 24}, {46, 18}, {63, 64}, {23, 30}}
2037.98

{{42, 65}, {14, 59}, {97, 10}, {13, 1}, {2, 8}, {88, 80}, {24, 36}, {95, 94}, {18, 9}, {66, 64},
 {91, 5}, {99, 25}, {6, 66}, {48, 55}, {83, 54}, {15, 65}, {10, 60}, {35, 86}, {44, 19}, {48, 43},
 {47, 86}, {29, 5}, {15, 45}, {75, 41}, {9, 9}, {23, 100}, {22, 82}, {34, 21}, {7, 34}, {54, 83}}
3382.46

{{68, 35}, {43, 63}, {66, 98}, {60, 56}, {57, 44}, {90, 52}, {36, 26}, {23, 55}, {66, 1}, {25, 6},
 {84, 65}, {38, 16}, {47, 31}, {44, 90}, {2, 30}, {87, 40}, {19, 51}, {75, 5}, {31, 94}, {85, 56},
 {95, 81}, {79, 80}, {82, 45}, {95, 10}, {27, 15}, {18, 70}, {24, 6}, {12, 73}, {10, 31}, {4, 29},
 {79, 93}, {45, 85}, {12, 10}, {89, 70}, {46, 5}, {56, 67}, {58, 59}, {92, 19}, {83, 49}, {22,77}}
3337.62

{{15, 22}, {71, 65}, {12, 35}, {30, 92}, {12, 92}, {97, 31}, {4, 32}, {39, 43}, {11, 40}, 
 {20, 15}, {71, 100}, {84, 76}, {51, 98}, {35, 94}, {46, 54}, {89, 49}, {28, 35}, {65, 42}, 
 {31, 41}, {48, 34}, {57, 46}, {14, 20}, {45, 28}, {82, 65}, {88, 78}, {55, 30}, {30, 27}, 
 {26, 47}, {51, 93}, {9, 95}, {56, 82}, {86, 56}, {46, 28}, {62, 70}, {98, 10}, {3, 39}, 
 {11, 34}, {17, 64}, {36, 42}, {52, 100}, {38, 11}, {83, 14}, {5, 17}, {72, 70}, {3, 97}, 
 {8, 94}, {64, 60}, {47, 25}, {99, 26}, {99, 69}}
3514.46
```

Comment: Can we reformat the input to suit our needs, by replacing the delimiters and such?

Comment: Specifically, I would like to replace the delimiters in a way that makes the list a valid PostScript User Path, so I can parse the whole thing with one `upath` operator. (It is actually an extremely simple 1:1 conversion between the seperators. `}, {` just becomes `lineto`, and the comma between the x and y is removed, and the opening and closing braces are replaced with a static header and footer...)

Comment: @AJMansfield I usually don't mind using convenient, native list representations, but using `upath` and `lineto` sounds like you're actually preprocessing the input. I.e. you're not taking a list of coordinates but an actual polygon.

Comment: Can we assume that the polygons are generic enough that there are no triple (or higher) intersections?

Comment: Do you have a reference about the consistency of the even-odd rule? Drawing the line in different directions will result in different number of crossing times.

Comment: @MattNoonan Oh, that's a good point. Yes you may assume that.

Comment: @Ray While the direction may affect the number of crossings, it will only ever increase or decrease by 2, preserving the parity. I'll try to find a reference. For a start, [SVG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Even%E2%80%93odd_rule) uses the same definition.

Comment: By the way, the even-odd rule works because of the following: starting outside the polygon and moving from left to right, top to bottom, perform rasterization as follows: every time you cross a boundary line of the polygon switch from "drawing" to "not drawing" (or vice versa) until having exited the polygon.  Any given horizontal print will cross the boundary line exactly an even number of times (the shape is *closed,* so this statement is mathematically true). Ergo, any *odd* number of crossings is *inside* the polygon.

Comment: I don't want to bump this unnecessarily, but technically you are drawing a ray, since lines are bi-infinite but rays are semi-infinite.

Comment: Mathematica 12.0 has a new built-in function for this: [`CrossingPolygon`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/CrossingPolygon.html).

Comment: @alephalpha The Mathematica input Area[CrossingPolygon[{{...},{...}}]] gives Area=24 for the first test case. All other results are as specified in the test case description.

Comment: @HugoPfoertner That's interesting. I don't know if this is a bug of Mathematica.

Comment: @alephalpha That may be. The graphics Mma creates with Graphics [CrossingPolygon [..]] for the first polygon is exactly the same as the one shown in the challenge description and has area 17 of the black part. I don't know the Mathematica world well enough to know how to report a suspected bug.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

## Mathematica, <s>247</s> <s>225</s> 222

```
p=Partition[#,2,1,1]&;{a_,b_}~r~{c_,d_}=Det/@{{a-c,c-d},{a,c}-b}/Det@{a-b,c-d};f=Abs@Tr@MapIndexed[Det@#(-1)^Tr@#2&,p[Join@@MapThread[{1-#,#}&/@#.#2&,{Sort/@Cases[{s_,t_}/;0<=s<=1&&0<=t<=1:>s]/@Outer[r,#,#,1],#}]&@p@#]]/2&
```

First add the points of intersection to the polygon, then reverse some of the edges, then its area can be calculated just like a simple polygon.

[image]

Example:

```
In[2]:= f[{{15, 22}, {71, 65}, {12, 35}, {30, 92}, {12, 92}, {97, 31}, {4, 32}, {39, 43}, {11, 40}, 
 {20, 15}, {71, 100}, {84, 76}, {51, 98}, {35, 94}, {46, 54}, {89, 49}, {28, 35}, {65, 42}, 
 {31, 41}, {48, 34}, {57, 46}, {14, 20}, {45, 28}, {82, 65}, {88, 78}, {55, 30}, {30, 27}, 
 {26, 47}, {51, 93}, {9, 95}, {56, 82}, {86, 56}, {46, 28}, {62, 70}, {98, 10}, {3, 39}, 
 {11, 34}, {17, 64}, {36, 42}, {52, 100}, {38, 11}, {83, 14}, {5, 17}, {72, 70}, {3, 97}, 
 {8, 94}, {64, 60}, {47, 25}, {99, 26}, {99, 69}}]

Out[2]= 3387239559852305316061173112486233884246606945138074528363622677708164\
 6419838924305735780894917246019722157041758816629529815853144003636562\
 9161985438389053702901286180223793349646170997160308182712593965484705\
 3835036745220226127640955614326918918917441670126958689133216326862597\
 0109115619/\
 9638019709367685232385259132839493819254557312303005906194701440047547\
 1858644412915045826470099500628074171987058850811809594585138874868123\
 9385516082170539979030155851141050766098510400285425157652696115518756\
 3100504682294718279622934291498595327654955812053471272558217892957057\
 556160

In[3]:= N[%] (*The numerical value of the last output*)

Out[3]= 3514.46
```

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not sure this logic will work for all situations.  Can you try `{1,2},{4,4},{4,2},{2,4},{2,1},{5,3}`?  You should come out with 3.433333333333309.  I looked at using a similar logic.

Comment: @MickyT Yes, it works. It returned `103/30`, and the numerical value is `3.43333`.

Comment: Sorry about that.  Good solution

Answer (score 45):

## Python 2, <del>323</del> 319 bytes

```py
exec u"def I(s,a,b=1j):c,d=s;d-=c;c-=a;e=(d*bX;return e*(0<=(b*cX*e<=e*e)and[a+(d*cX*b/e]or[]\nE=lambda p:zip(p,p[1:]+p);S=sorted;P=E(input());print sum((t-b)*(r-l)/2Fl,r@E(S(i.realFa,b@PFe@PFi@I(e,a,b-a)))[:-1]Fb,t@E(S(((i+j)XFe@PFi@I(e,l)Fj@I(e,r)))[::2])".translate({70:u" for ",64:u" in ",88:u".conjugate()).imag"})
```

Takes a list of vertices through STDIN as complex numbers, in the following form

```
[  X + Yj,  X + Yj,  ...  ]
```

, and writes the result to STDOUT.

Same code after string replacement and some spacing:

```py
def I(s, a, b = 1j):
    c, d = s; d -= c; c -= a;
    e = (d*b.conjugate()).imag;
    return e * (0 <= (b*c.conjugate()).imag * e <= e*e) and \
           [a + (d*c.conjugate()).imag * b/e] or []

E = lambda p: zip(p, p[1:] + p);
S = sorted;

P = E(input());

print sum(
    (t - b) * (r - l) / 2

    for l, r in E(S(
        i.real for a, b in P for e in P for i in I(e, a, b - a)
    ))[:-1]

    for b, t in E(S(
        ((i + j).conjugate()).imag for e in P for i in I(e, l) for j in I(e, r)
    ))[::2]
)
```

### Explanation

For each point of intersection of two sides of the input polygon (including the vertices), pass a vertical line though that point.

[image: Figure 1]

(In fact, due to golfing, the program passes a few more lines; it doesn't really matter, as long as we pass at least these lines.)
The body of the polygon between any two consecutive lines is comprised of vertical trapezoids (and triangles, and line segments, as special cases of those).
It has to be the case, since if any of these shapes had an additional vertex between the two bases, there would be another vertical line through that point, between the two lines in question.
The sum of the areas of all such trapezoids is the area of the polygon.

Here's how we find these trapezoids:
For each pair of consecutive vertical lines, we find the segments of each side of the polygon that (properly) lie between these two lines (which might not exist for some of the sides).
In the above illustration, these are the six red segments, when considering the two red vertical lines.
Note that these segments don't properly intersect each other (i.e., they may only meet at their end points, completely coincide or not intersect at all, since, once again, if they properly intersected there would be another vertical line in between;) and so it makes sense to talk about ordering them top-to-bottom, which we do.
According to the even-odd rule, once we cross the first segment, we're inside the polygon; once we cross the second one, we're out; the third one, in again; the fourth, out; and so on...
In other words, if we group the segments into consecutive pairs, each pair is the legs of one of the trapezoids.

Overall, this is an *O*(*n*<sup>3</sup> log *n*) algorithm.

Comment: This is brilliant! I knew I could count on you for this one. ;) (You might want to answer [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10049454/1633117) over on Stack Overflow.)

Comment: @MartinBüttner Keep 'em coming :)

Comment: Great work and a great explanation

Comment: WHile I can imagine that there might be some pathological cases that this technique would fail on (most of them calculus-related, and obviously with more than 50 points), this is some pretty neat code. I might just steal the technique for my answer.

Comment: This is an impressive answer. Did you develop the algorithm yourself or is there existing work on this problem? If there is existing work, I would appreciate a pointer to where I can find it. I had no idea on how to tackle this.

Comment: Not relevant to the golfing part but if you keep track of the ordering of the line-segments you don't need to sort at every step. Instead do one step of bubble sorting and insert/remove newly appearing/disappearing lines for a total cost of O(n^3). (n^2 * n for the bubble sorts and n * n for adding/removing lines)

Comment: @CarpetPython I developed it myself, but I'd be very surprised if it hasn't been done before.

Comment: @MartinBüttner Thanks for the bounty :)

Answer (score 9):

## Haskell, 549

It doesn't look like I can golf this one down far enough, but the concept was different than the other two answers so I figured I'd share it anyway. It performs O(N^2) rational operations to compute the area.

```
import Data.List
_%0=2;x%y=x/y
h=sort
z f w@(x:y)=zipWith f(y++[x])w
a=(%2).sum.z(#);(a,b)#(c,d)=b*c-a*d
(r,p)?(s,q)=[(0,p)|p==q]++[(t,v t p r)|u t,u$f r]where f x=(d q p#x)%(r#s);t=f s;u x=x^2<x
v t(x,y)(a,b)=(x+t*a,y+t*b);d=v(-1)
s x=zip(z d x)x
i y=h.(=<<y).(?)=<<y
[]!x=[x];x!_=x
e n(a@(x,p):y)|x>0=(n!y,a):(e(n!y)$tail$dropWhile((/=p).snd)y)|0<1=(n,a):e n y
c[p]k=w x[]where((_,q):x)=e[]p;w((n,y):z)b|q==y=(k,map snd(q:b)):c n(-k)|0<1=w z(y:b);c[]_=[]
b(s,p)=s*a p
u(_,x)(_,y)=h x==h y
f p=abs$sum$map b$nubBy u$take(length p^2)$c[cycle$i$s p]1
```

*Example:*

```
λ> f test''
33872395598523053160611731124862338842466069451380745283636226777081646419838924305735780894917246019722157041758816629529815853144003636562916198543838905370290128618022379334964617099716030818271259396548470538350367452202261276409556143269189189174416701269586891332163268625970109115619 % 9638019709367685232385259132839493819254557312303005906194701440047547185864441291504582647009950062807417198705885081180959458513887486812393855160821705399790301558511410507660985104002854251576526961155187563100504682294718279622934291498595327654955812053471272558217892957057556160
λ> fromRational (f test'')
3514.4559380388832
```

The idea is to rewire the polygon at every crossing, resulting in a union of polygons with no intersecting edges.  We can then compute the (signed) area of each of the polygons using Gauss' shoelace formula (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shoelace_formula).  The even-odd rule demands that when a crossing is converted, the area of the new polygon is counted negatively relative to the old polygon.

For example, consider the polygon in the original question. The crossing in the upper-left is converted to two paths which only meet at a point; the two paths are both oriented clockwise, so the areas of each would be positive unless we declared that the inner path is weighted by -1 relative to the outer path.  This is equivalent to alphaalpha's path reversal.

[image: Polygons derived from original example]

As another example, consider the polygon from MickyT's comment:

[image: Polygons derived from MickyT's comment]

Here, some of the polygons are oriented clockwise and some counterclockwise. The sign-flip-on-crossing rule ensures that the clockwise-oriented regions pick up an extra factor of -1, causing them to contribute a positive amount to the area.

Here's how the program works:

```
import Data.List  -- for sort and nubBy

-- Rational division, with the unusual convention that x/0 = 2
_%0=2;x%y=x/y

-- Golf
h=sort

-- Define a "cyclic zipWith" operation. Given a list [a,b,c,...z] and a binary
-- operation (@), z (@) [a,b,c,..z] computes the list [b@a, c@b, ..., z@y, a@z]
z f w@(x:y)=zipWith f(y++[x])w

-- The shoelace formula for the signed area of a polygon
a=(%2).sum.z(#)

-- The "cross-product" of two 2d vectors, resulting in a scalar.
(a,b)#(c,d)=b*c-a*d

-- Determine if the line segment from p to p+r intersects the segment from
-- q to q+s.  Evaluates to the singleton list [(t,x)] where p + tr = x is the
-- point of intersection, or the empty list if there is no intersection. 
(r,p)?(s,q)=[(0,p)|p==q]++[(t,v t p r)|u t,u$f r]where f x=(d q p#x)%(r#s);t=f s;u x=x^2<x

-- v computes an affine combination of two vectors; d computes the difference
-- of two vectors.
v t(x,y)(a,b)=(x+t*a,y+t*b);d=v(-1)

-- If x is a list of points describing a polygon, s x will be the list of
-- (displacement, point) pairs describing the edges.
s x=zip(z d x)x

-- Given a list of (displacement, point) pairs describing a polygon's edges,
-- create a new polygon which also has a vertex at every point of intersection.
-- Mercilessly golfed.
i y=h.(=<<y).(?)=<<y


-- Extract a simple polygon; when an intersection point is reached, fast-forward
-- through the polygon until we return to the same point, then continue.  This
-- implements the edge rewiring operation. Also keep track of the first
-- intersection point we saw, so that we can process that polygon next and with
-- opposite sign.
[]!x=[x];x!_=x
e n(a@(x,p):y)|x>0=(n!y,a):(e(n!y)$tail$dropWhile((/=p).snd)y)|0<1=(n,a):e n y

-- Traverse the polygon from some arbitrary starting point, using e to extract
-- simple polygons marked with +/-1 weights.
c[p]k=w x[]where((_,q):x)=e[]p;w((n,y):z)b|q==y=(k,map snd(q:b)):c n(-k)|0<1=w z(y:b);c[]_=[]

-- If the original polygon had N vertices, there could (very conservatively)
-- be up to N^2 points of intersection.  So extract N^2 polygons using c,
-- throwing away duplicates, and add up the weighted areas of each polygon.
b(s,p)=s*a p
u(_,x)(_,y)=h x==h y
f p=abs$sum$map b$nubBy u$take(length p^2)$c[cycle$i$s p]1
```