# Area of Polygon

Tags: code-golf, geometry

Given the number of vertices `N` of a convex polygon and each of their `(x, y)` calculate the polygon's area. vertexes are in clockwise order

You must handle all `N <= 45` ,`-600 <= x,y <= 600`, and your answer must be accurate to at least 2 decimal places.

Example:

```
3
 1 6
 1 2
-4 2
```

The area is 10.00.

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), fewest bytes wins.
Input to be taken in code.

Comment: What order are the vertices given in? Can we assume the polygon is always convex?

Comment: Does the input have to be taken in the format of the example? There's no reason for the scripting languages only restriction, and I don't even know what that means.

Comment: "Code in scripting languages only" is subjective (what qualifies as a scripting language?) and likely excludes many of the languages commonly used on the site. It's an arbitrary and unnecessary condition.

Comment: Sounds like a good challenge, but bad written.

Comment: As edited, this question is a duplicate of http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/47638/194

Comment: About clockwise direction, I think, it is worse. It should be random order like before, instead.

Comment: The polygon will be convex hull, so it is unique. Prove me that it is wrong.

Comment: After then number of vertex is redudant

Comment: @PeterTaylor Why is that? Isn't determining the area of a complex polygon much simpler than determining that of a self-intersecting polygon with even-odd area counting rule?

Comment: @MartinBüttner, the standard approach uses the exact same techniques that are used in the answers to the other question. The answers will be shorter because they only need to track two extrema rather than a sorted list of lines, but I that doesn't mean they will be fundamentally different. Although I suppose, on reflection, that there would be other techniques available (use the centroid to split the polygon into triangles). If you want to reopen it, go ahead, but first please edit to clarify whether the vertices are integers or doubles.

Comment: @PeterTaylor "They are fudamentally using the same approach. It's only some minor details in the other question which have contributed 87% of the code size!"

Answer (score 5):

## Mathematica, 29 bytes

```
RegionMeasure@*ConvexHullMesh
```

Example usage:

```
(RegionMeasure@*ConvexHullMesh)[{{1, 6}, {1, 2}, {-4, 2}}]
(* 10. *)
```

Comment: perfect tool for the job

Comment: @phase Even so, I know I'm still going to be beat by the golfing languages. =)

Comment: Someone needs to make Pyth for Mathematica

Comment: @phase Hmmm what a good idea ;)

Comment: `Area@*Polygon`

Answer (score 2):

## JavaScript (ES6) 131

```js
f=l=>(p=l.pop(t=Math.atan2),l.sort((a,b)=>t(a.y-p.y,a.x-p.x)-t(b.y-p.y,b.x-p.x)),[...l,p].map(t=>(v+=p.x*t.y-p.y*t.x,p=t),v=0),v/2)

// More readable
u=l=>(
  t=Math.atan2,
  p=l.pop(),
  l.sort((a,b)=>t(a.y-p.y,a.x-p.x)-t(b.y-p.y,b.x-p.x)),
  v=0,
  [...l,p].map(t=>(v+=p.x*t.y-p.y*t.x,p=t)),
  v/2  
) 

//TEST
console.log=x=>O.innerHTML+=x+'\n'

T=[{x:1,y:6},{x:1,y:2},{x:-4,y:2}] // area 10
console.log(JSON.stringify(T)+' '+f(T))
T=[{x:12,y:12},{x:2,y:2},{x:4,y:10},{x:11,y:2}] // area 75
console.log(JSON.stringify(T)+' '+f(T))
```

```html
<pre id=O></pre>
```

Answer (score 1):

### C# - 268

with all the output handling included, yup this ain't gonna win

```
using System;class P{static void Main(string[]a){int i,v=int.Parse(a[0]),j=v-1;var x=new float[v];var y=new float[v];for(i=0;i++<v;){x[i-1]=float.Parse(a[i]);y[i-1]=float.Parse(a[i+v]);}fl‌​oat s=0;for(i=0;i<v;j=i++)s+=(x[j]+x[i])*(y[j]-y[i]);Console.Write(s/2);}}
```

Program reads input from the string array **args**. Example input: 3 1 1 -4 6 2 2. Output: 10

First number is the number of vertices, all the rest are X & Y coordinates. After vertice number input all x coordinates, then all y coordinates, each one separated by whitespace.

I'm not fully certain if I need to include **using, namespace, main void etc...** but I included them anyway.

EDIT: Saved some bytes, thanks to @edc65 !

Comment: You need to take the input in code.

Comment: @hotrod Alright, one second.

Comment: @hotrod Done. See the explanation.

Comment: namespace is not needed and `Program` could be P

Comment: and surely yod don't need `console.read()` at the end

Comment: The same program, golfed: 262 `using System;class P{static void Main(string[]a){int i,v=int.Parse(a[0]),j=v-1;var x=new float[v];var y=new float[v];for(i=0;i++<v;){x[i-1]=float.Parse(a[i]);y[i-1]=float.Parse(a[i+v]);}float s=0;for(i=0;i<v;j=i++)s+=(x[j]+x[i])*(y[j]-y[i]);Console.Write(s/2);}}`

Comment: @edc65 Alright, next time I know what to include in the byte count :D I know I don't need to stop the console at the end, I just didn't see any way of me winning with C# so didn't golf it to the end :P Thanks for the golfed one still, looks nice!

Comment: To have the console app stopping: run without debug (Ctrl f5)

Comment: @edc65 Didn't know that o.O Thanks for telling!